# Access address of Field within Structure variable in Golang

Tags: pointers, go

How to access the pointer or the address of a FIELD within a STRUCTURE in GOLANG. I have the  address or pointer of the whole structure variable but can not properly access the address of the field inside structure. So far I have tried Reflection but seems breaking somewhere. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type S struct{ F1, F2 int }

func main() {
    s := new(S)
    f1, f2 := &s.F1, &s.F2
    fmt.Printf("%p %p %p\n", s, f1, f2)
}
```

Output:

```
0x1040a128 0x1040a128 0x1040a12c
```

Comment: thank you for sharing. It looks really simple but following fails in my code 
final.id =  &(intermediate.ID()). id field in final is a string *, while intermediate.ID() returns a string. Currently I have to create an temporary variable to hold the intermediate.ID() value and then assign its address. I wish to avoid the temporary variable.