# Why is fmt.Println not consistent when printing pointers?

Tags: pointers, go

I'm an experienced programmer but have never before touched Go in my life.

I just started playing around with it and I found that `fmt.Println()` will actually print the values of pointers prefixed by `&`, which is neat.

However, it doesn't do this with all types. I'm pretty sure it is because the types it does not work with are primitives (or at least, Java would call them that, does Go?).

Does anyone know why this inconsistent behaviour exists in the Go `fmt` library? I can easily retrieve the value by using `*p`, but for some reason `Println` doesn't do this.

Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type X struct {
    S string
}

func main() {
    x := X{"Hello World"}
    fmt.Println(&x)     // &{Hello World} <-- displays the pointed-to value prefixed with &
    fmt.Println(*(&x))  // {Hello World}

    i := int(1)
    fmt.Println(&i)     // 0x10410028     <-- instead of &1 ?
    fmt.Println(*(&i))  // 1
}
```

Comment: That seems right.  0x10410028 is the address of 1. Whereas X{} is an empty struct which has is no address so &{}.  Empty structs don't take space. Change `type X struct{}` to `type X int` and see what happens.

Comment: The default format is `%v`, and the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing) lists the default format for each type.

Comment: @reticentroot Oh, I was trying to give a minimal working example. I've edited the struct to include a string; same behaviour.

Comment: @JimB Ok good, but then the question remains: Why did they not give primitive types a `'&' + printable value` for `%v`? That seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers https://goplay.space/#JbyofJq88Y works as expected.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers example 2.. https://goplay.space/#umNrESpnqY , see this article 
https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/25/the-empty-struct
also 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752447/access-address-of-field-within-structure-variable-in-golang

Comment: @JochemKuijpers: they made `%v` print some useful defaults. You don't normally print pointers to ints, so it wasn't included as a default format. These aren't meant to be tightly specified for machine consumption, this is for human readable output, and if the default doesn't print exactly what you want you can choose to format it another way. It prints what it prints because the authors wrote it that way

Comment: @reticentroot RE: Example 2. How does that work? Does the variable `x` not have an address, even though I can make a pointer for it?

Comment: @JochemKuijpers In example two X is no longer an empty struct.  It hold data of type string.  The struct allocates memory to hold your string data. Therefore X.S has an address, whereas In the first example you have an empty struct... there is nothing allocate and Go is knows that so no address is returned. You can take advantage of that fact for example, in implementing a set using a map, map[string]bool vs map[string]struct{}{}, the second will use less memory because struct takes no space and can be nil.

Comment: @reticentroot I think you missed my edit. I added a string to my original X struct, and it's pointer still does not display an address. My (only) question boils down to: Why does it not display an address?

Comment: @JochemKuijpers Thats normal print behavior as Jim said. If you `fmt.Println(&x.S)` you'll get the address of the string.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938612/how-do-i-print-the-pointer-value-of-a-go-object-what-does-the-pointer-value-mea

If you `fmt.Printf("%p\n", &x)` you'll get the address of the struct itself

Also read https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "technical" answer to your question can be found here:

https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go?#L839

As you can see, when printing pointers to Array, Slice, Struct or Map types, the special rule of printing "&" + value applies, but in all other cases the address is printed.

As for why they decided to only apply the rule for those, it seems the authors considered that for "compound" objects you'd be interested in always seeing the values (even when using a pointer), but for other simple values this was not the case.

You can see that reasoning here, where they added the rule for the Map type which was not there before:

https://github.com/golang/go/commit/a0c5adc35cbfe071786b6115d63abc7ad90578a9#diff-ebda2980233a5fb8194307ce437dd60a

I would guess this had to do with the fact that it is very common to use for example pointers to Struct to pass them around (so many times you'd just forget to de-reference the pointer when wanting to print the value), but no so common to use pointers to int or string to pass those around (so if you were printing the pointer you were probably interested in seeing the actual address).